# AzureDevop release pipeline does not run program tests

Tags: azure-devops

Helo, I'm hopeless. I have build pipeline and release pipeline. In both pipeline i have Run Test task. In build pipeline everything works perfect and i have test results. But if I get this build and use in release pipeline, program does not find  any test. Task configuration is the same in both pipelienes. Can someone help me. Thanks a lot.

[image: BuildTask]
[image: ReleaseTask]

Answer (score 0):

on the end after 2 days, I'm found solution of this problem. In my release pipeline, I added add NuGet tasks to install MSTest.TestAdapter and MSTest.TestFramework. I hope this solution save some time to the others.

[image]

Comment: Much appreciate this solution shared here! You can accept your answer, so that others could directly know this is work.